# imap server fetch not working properly

Tags: email, imap

I'm currently working on my own IMAP server.
When i get a FETCH request for 3 mails and i send a response with 3 mails, the client does not seem to recognise my response. (my client reports that there is no mail)

This is the request and response (C is client, S is server):

```
C: 405 UID FETCH 4,3,1 (INTERNALDATE RFC822.SIZE FLAGS BODY.PEEK[HEADER.FIELDS (subject from date content-type to cc message-id references importance reply-to)])

S: * 3 FETCH (UID 4 RFC822.SIZE 332 INTERNALDATE "<date>" FLAGS (\Recent) BODY[HEADER.FIELDS (SUBJECT FROM DATE CONTENT-TYPE TO CC MESSAGE-ID REFERENCES IMPORTANCE REPLY-TO)] {317}
Subject: <subject>
From: <email>
Date: <date>
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=ISO-8859-1; format=flowed
To: <email>
CC: <email>
Message-ID: <messid>
Reply-To: <email>
)
S: * 2 FETCH (UID 3 RFC822.SIZE 731 INTERNALDATE "<date>" FLAGS (\Recent) BODY[HEADER.FIELDS (SUBJECT FROM DATE CONTENT-TYPE TO CC MESSAGE-ID REFERENCES IMPORTANCE REPLY-TO)] {231}
Subject: <subject>
From: <email>
Date: <date>
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=ISO-8859-1; format=flowed
Message-ID: <messid>
Reply-To: <email>
)
S: * 1 FETCH (UID 1 RFC822.SIZE 400 INTERNALDATE "<date>" FLAGS (\Answered \Recent) BODY[HEADER.FIELDS (SUBJECT FROM DATE CONTENT-TYPE TO CC MESSAGE-ID REFERENCES IMPORTANCE REPLY-TO)] {252}
Subject: <subject>
From: <email>
Date: <date>
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=ISO-8859-1; format=flowed
To: <email>
Message-ID: <messid>
Reply-To: <email>
)
S: 405 OK UID FETCH completed
```

where (subject) is the actual subject, (email) are valid emailadresses, (date) is the date and (messid) is a unique message-id.

Does somebody see what i am doing wrong here. maybe i am sending the wrong response, or am i doing something else wrong?
can someone help me with this?

so far, anything else (login, list, search) works fine. if it is needed, i could send those requests/responses as well

thanx i advance.

Comment: Nothing pops out as wrong. Can you confirm that you end of lines are CRLF, and not just LF? Many clients depend on that. Also, are you positive your byte counts are correct, and that you have another CRLF after your literal (looks like it, I see the closing parentheses)

Comment: my line-endings are CRLF. in c# I use "\r\n". the bytecounts are calculated as follows: RFC822.SIZE = (headersize) + (bodysize). headersize = length of all headerlines including CRLF's. bodysize = length of the body-text. adding an extra CRLF between the fetch responses or sending the responses at once instead of seperated also doesn't work

Comment: Can you show an EXACT response that fails?

Comment: 'recognised' is maybe not the right word. after the last repsonse ("405 OK UID FETCH completed") the client does not ask for anything else, and indicates that he has stopped loading. he says there is no mail available, even when i set the number of mails to load to "all". (sorry if my english is not very good)

Comment: @arnt: for as far as i know, the response does not fail, but the client stops requesting after "405 OK UID FETCH completed". as long as that response it not sent, the client does not give any indication of stopping at all, it keeps showing a loading-sign

Comment: Can you try a more minimal case, with only one message, and where you can provide the entirety of the interaction?  What client are you using?

Comment: @Max: as a client i use the email-app from an android 2.3 mobile phone. as mentioned before, the client stops loading directly after receiving the final response ("405 OK UID FETCH completed"). maybe there's a problem in the individual fetch-respones. does the order in which the parameters (INTERNALDATE or RFC822-SIZE) are returned matter? and does it matter wheter i use capitals or not?

Comment: Order should not matter. IMAP is supposed to be case insensitive.

Comment: Try it with a different client and see if it works. I've had issues in the past because different client request different attributes (e.g. some use ENVELOPE and others don't); like that you may be able to pinpoint a particular attribute that you may not be constructing correctly.

Comment: @Gigi: i tried it with a php-client, and after implementing some more attributes of FETCH, it actually worked with that client. unfortuntely, it still does not work with my android, but at least i can continue developing my server. thanx!